# add key in hash based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following method

```
def some_method
   ...do something here...

    @customer_info = {
      a: a,
      b: b
    }
end
```

I want to add key c in @customer_info if variable `customer` is `true`
so something like,

```
@customer_info = {
  a: a,
  b: b,
  c: something if customer is true
}
```

tried to do something like this but no luck

```
@customer_info.merge(customer.present? {c: something} : {})
```

Comment: What do you mean, "no luck"? Your approach works for me in console. (You're missing a `?` in your ternary operator, though.)

Comment: Did you just forget that `Hash#merge` *returns* the updated Hash rather than modifying it in-place?

Comment: You can use `@customer_info.merge!({c: something}) if customer` but `@customer_info[:c] = something if customer` is more efficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@customer_info[:c] = something if customer
```

Comment: A variant is `@customer_info = { a: a,  b: b }.tap { |h| @customer_info[:c] = something if customer }`, which returns the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are simply missing `?` in your ternary operator?

Your approach seems to work for me in console:

```
> customer_info = {a: :a, b: :b}
 => {:a=>:a, :b=>:b} 
> c = false
 => false 

> customer_info.merge(c ? {c: c} : {})
 => {:a=>:a, :b=>:b} 

> c = true
 => true 
> customer_info.merge(c ? {c: c} : {})
 => {:a=>:a, :b=>:b, :c=>true}
```

So, this:

```
@customer_info.merge(customer.present? {c: something} : {})
```

Should be more like:

```
@customer_info.merge(customer.present? ? {c: something} : {})
```

---

**Quick Update**

As pointed out in the comments, this should be more like:

```
@customer_info.merge!({c: something}) if customer.present?
```

The commentators do a nice job of explaining why.

Comment: I think the OP meant to use `merge!` to modify the `Hash` in place rather than returning a copy with the information merged in. Additionally this would be traditionally written as `@customer_info.merge!({c: something}) if customer.present?` rather than placing the ternary inside the parens